# Dreamhost how host polymer web app

Tags: gulp, polymer, hosting, dreamhost

Happy xmas to all .
I would ask how can I use on my hosting polymer dreamhost, I found nothing on the net and assistance of dreamhost told me that they do not officially support it, some of you managed to make it work? the result for now is the following http://pillsoft.com/test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any hosting issue here, but I do see your app is missing critical files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes , i see it after . i try to upload a simple starter kit and it works , i mistake a route or something else .
Anyway dreamhost support polymer